# Force selenium to open desktop version of site rather than mobile

Tags: python, selenium, dataframe, selenium-chromedriver, desktop

I've written some code to scrape futures prices. On my work laptop, the website opens in mobile mode as opposed to desktop. This results in the DataFrame being return as a multi-index object, and throws an error saying "DataFrame has no attribute str". I've tried to drop the index, reset the index, etc. and no luck.

If I run this exact code on my personal laptop, it runs with no issue and returns exactly what I want it to. Any help on getting the Chrome webdriver to open the site in desktop mode would be greatly appreciated. I've tried setting the window size, and tried maximizing the page, yet nothing seems to work to open the desktop version.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import os
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd
import time
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\TEMP\ChromeDriver\chromedriver.exe")
driver.set_window_size(1920,1080)
driver.get('http://cmegroup.com/trading/agricultural/grain-and-oilseed/soybean.html')
time.sleep(3)
table = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#quotesFuturesProductTable1').get_attribute('outerHTML')
soup = BeautifulSoup(table, 'html.parser')
df = pd.read_html(str(soup))[0]
df = df[df.Month.str[0:3]=='NOV']  **This is where it throws the error that DataFrame has no attribute string, yet exact code works on my personal laptop as the desktop version does not come back as a multi-index

print(df)
browser.quit()
```

Comment: user-agent property can sometimes be the issue here. Do you know what user-agent you're sending?

Comment: I do not. How would I go about finding that, or what would I need to do to set it correctly?