# How to close a pop up html element in Chrome using Selenium with Python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to build a web scraper to search through the online Disney store and send me an alert any time a new product is listed or a price is changed. Things had been going well, but recently Disney added a new pop-up window to their online store that is interfering with my script.
[image: Disney Store pop up]

This new pop-up window must be closed by selecting the "X", "No Thanks", or by clicking outside of the box. When I try to select the "X" or "No Thanks" buttons in my script by id or xpath I'm met with "Unable to locate element." When inspecting the element, the html does not appear to be a part of the original product page. I'm not sure how to interact with this new layer on top of the web page, and it is causing my script to fail because I cannot interact with the original page without dismissing the pop-up.

A portion of my script is listed for reference. The Disney website loads while scrolling, so the While loop checks the scroll height and continues to scroll after each block of products is loaded. When the pop-up window pops up, the while loop fails and the product list is cut short.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from time import sleep

# Path to chromedriver.exe
PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
# Add an option to disable notifications/pop ups
options = Options()
options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
options.headless = False
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH, options=options)
# url of the disney online store, filtered on Jasmine
url = "https://www.shopdisney.com/characters/disney/disney-princess/jasmine/?originalTerm=jasmine&searchType=redirect&pdpRedirect=0"
# Open a disney store session
driver.get(url)
# Select the sort button, sort by Newest items
sort = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"sort__dropdown-trigger").click()
newest = driver.find_element(By.ID, "sortListBox-newest").click()
# Give the site a second to load before continuing
sleep(1)

# Set a time to wait between attempting to scroll page
SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME = 2
# Get scroll height
last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
while True:
    # Scroll down to bottom
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight-1500);")
    # Wait to load page
    sleep(SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME)
    # Calculate new scroll height and compare with last scroll height
    new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    if new_height == last_height:
        break
    last_height = new_height
    
# Store all of the product items on the website to a list item for later comparison
products = []
for product in driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME,"product"):
    products.append(product.text)
```

Comment: Probably something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27270357/closing-a-generic-pop-up-in-selenium.  I would think your `while` loop needs to constantly check to see if that popup is present, and if so, get rid of it.  Or, it could be present on the page already (and the opacity of it simply changes to give off a "pop-up" feel), in which case, you should be able to close it/delete it right away.

Comment: I checked the URL you posted, but I am not getting that pop-up, post the exact URL. May be that pop-up is an iframe, check the page source.  If it is an iframe, get the property of that iframe, switch to it, close that pop-up, then switch to default content.

Comment: @Jujimufoo Is the pop-up sits inside of an Iframe element? What is the full error that you get?

Comment: @AbiSaran I believe Selenium is opening the browser in a mobile format; the pop up does not appear when browsing from a PC.

Comment: @TalAngel The pop-up does not produce an error, rather it causes the While loop to no longer function and therefore does not load the full contents of the page. Any errors that are induced come from other parts of the code.

Comment: @TimothyG. I have also reviewed that question and the answers provided, but I am not sure how to implement a check in my While loop for this pop-up element. However the pop-up is being loaded is not found within the URL used in the driver.get(url) command. Inspecting the xpath and attempting to close it did not seem to work, nor did disabling notifications. This question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62883027/force-selenium-to-open-desktop-version-of-site-rather-than-mobile seems similar to my issue, but there were no answers provided.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by specifying that selenium needs to launch the browser in desktop format, rather than using a mobile format. The popup window does not appear in the desktop version of the site, removing the source of the problem.

```
options = Options()
options.add_argument("user-agent=91.0.4472.114")
PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
url = "https://www.shopdisney.com/characters/disney/disney-princess/jasmine/?originalTerm=jasmine&searchType=redirect&pdpRedirect=0"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH, options=options)
driver.get(url)
```

I found the user-agent for Chrome from another webscraper I had written. I didn't fully understand this snippet of code before, but it saved me today.

```
headers = {
"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.114 Safari/537.36",
}
```